# How to call directory page inside the function in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I have created Exe file for my app using NSIS script.In my script i have checked free space for selected directory.

1.If selected directory dont have required space then user wants to change the directory.

2.After changing directory in directory page again wants to check free space.so when the required space is available for the selected directory then only proceed to next page.
So it will come under looping statement.I have tried following script

```
page custom checking
Function checking
Push "\"
push $InstallDir
Call SplitFirstStrPart
pop $R0
${DriveSpace} $R0 "/D=F /S=G" $R0
${While} $R0 <= 2
    MessageBox MB_OK "Expected free space is not availble"
    call directory
${EndWhile}
Function directory

--Here i want to define directory page--
[page directory] we cant use this here
call checking
FunctionEnd
```

1.How to create user defined directory page?

2.Is possible to call page directory or MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY multiple times?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a page from a function but you can skip a page by calling `Abort` in the page PRE callback and you can also [jump to any page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Go_to_a_NSIS_page).

You can have multiple pages of all page types:

```
!include MUI.nsh
Var dir1
Var dir2
Function .onInit
StrCpy $dir1 c:\default1
StrCpy $dir2 c:\default2
FunctionEnd
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VARIABLE $dir1
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VARIABLE $dir2
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
Section
DetailPrint $dir1
DetailPrint $dir2
SectionEnd
```